# Using simpy to model a network

Tags: python, networking, simpy

I am a new user for Simpy. I have a question on how to code the model of network process as shown in the picture:

[image]

For the network, the products need to move through the resources within the network according the its schedule and the sequence of the resources. In order to move the product to the next resource, the two resources ahead need to be available. otherwise, the product have to wait in the exiting resource (can not release the exiting resource).

In addition, each product has a size for calculating the time passing through each resource (block in the picture). When the product come to the end of the block sequence, it will be queue at other sides and continue process as a loop.

I have studied in the tutorial of Simpy, but i do not understand the way to model the series of resources. Therefore, if anyone could show me how to figure this problem, it will be very grateful.

```
import simpy

env = simpy.Environment()

B1 = simpy.Store(env, capacity=1)
B2 = simpy.Store(env, capacity=1)
B3 = simpy.Store(env, capacity=1)
B4 = simpy.Store(env, capacity=1)
B5 = simpy.Store(env, capacity=1)
B6 = simpy.Store(env, capacity=1)
B7 = simpy.Store(env, capacity=1)
B8 = simpy.Store(env, capacity=1)
B9 = simpy.Store(env, capacity=1)
B10 = simpy.Store(env, capacity=1)
B11 = simpy.Store(env, capacity=1)
B12 = simpy.Store(env, capacity=1)
B13 = simpy.Store(env, capacity=1)
B14 = simpy.Store(env, capacity=1)
B15 = simpy.Store(env, capacity=1)
B16 = simpy.Store(env, capacity=1)
B17 = simpy.Store(env, capacity=1)
B18 = simpy.Store(env, capacity=1)
B19 = simpy.Store(env, capacity=1)
B20 = simpy.Store(env, capacity=1)

def product_starter(env, B1, B11):

yield B1.put(1)
yield B11.put(2)
yield env.timeout(10)
yield B1.put(3)
yield B11.put(4)

def block(env, inblock, outblock , timeout):
    while True:
    product = yield inblock.get()
    yield env.timeout(timeout)
    yield outblock.put(product)
    print('product move')

env.process(product_starter(env, B1, B11))
env.process(block(env, B1, B2, 15))
env.process(block(env, B2, B3, 15))
env.process(block(env, B3, B4, 15))
env.process(block(env, B4, B5, 15))
env.process(block(env, B5, B6, 15))
env.process(block(env, B6, B7, 15))
env.process(block(env, B7, B8, 15))
env.process(block(env, B8, B9, 15))
env.process(block(env, B9, B10, 15))
env.process(block(env, B10, B11, 15))
env.process(block(env, B11, B12, 15))
env.process(block(env, B12, B13, 15))
env.process(block(env, B13, B14, 15))
env.process(block(env, B14, B15, 15))
env.process(block(env, B15, B16, 15))
env.process(block(env, B16, B17, 15))
env.process(block(env, B17, B18, 15))
env.process(block(env, B18, B19, 15))
env.process(block(env, B19, B20, 15))

env.run(until = 100)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have any code?

Comment: Yes, I have tried by using store. But I have no idea how to use resource to model  this

Comment: You should start with an extremely simple and reduced variant of your problem. Toy around with simpy, get comfortable with it and its resource types. Slowly add more complexity while you get a better idea of how everything works.